# Fit table in column (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table inside of a column but it is not fitting in the column;

I can not use row span because every record has a different number of dependent values.

Comment: please add code example on this content , I do not know what the problem is.

Comment: can you show us your code ?

Comment: Wow, not even a screenshot, just a picture of monitor showing the screen...

Answer (score 0):

You can always work with `rowspan` and `colspan` i.e.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Some data</td>
  <td>Some data</td>
  <td>Some data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">Some data</td>
  <td>Some data</td>
  <td>Some data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Some data</td>
  <td>Some data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Some data</td>
  <td colspan="2">Some data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Some data</td>
  <td>Some data</td>
  <td>Some data</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i am displaying dynamic values in side column so i can not hardcode rowspan="2"